Introduction to analytic number theory 8.8
Theorem 8.8
Let $f$ be completely multiplicative, and let $g(k)=\mu(k) h(k)$, where $h$ is multiplicative. Assume that $f(p) \neq 0$ and $f(p) \neq h(p)$ for all primes $p$, and let
$$
s_k(n)=\sum_{d \mid(n, k)} f(d) g\left(\frac{k}{d}\right) .
$$
Then we have
$$
s_k(n)=\frac{F(k) g(N)}{F(N)}
$$
where $F=f * g$ and $N=k /(n, k)$.
Proof. First we note that
$$
\begin{aligned}
F(k) & =\sum_{d \mid k} f(d) \mu\left(\frac{k}{d}\right) h\left(\frac{k}{d}\right)=\sum_{d \mid k} f\left(\frac{k}{d}\right) \mu(d) h(d)=f(k) \sum_{d \mid k} \mu(d) \frac{h(d)}{f(d)} \\
& =f(k) \prod_{p \mid k}\left(1-\frac{h(p)}{f(p)}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Next, we write $a=(n, k)$, so that $k=a N$. Then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
s_k(n) & =\sum_{d \mid a} f(d) \mu\left(\frac{k}{d}\right) h\left(\frac{k}{d}\right)=\sum_{d \mid a} f(d) \mu\left(\frac{a N}{d}\right) h\left(\frac{a N}{d}\right) \\
& =\sum_{d \mid a} f\left(\frac{a}{d}\right) \mu(N d) h(N d) .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now $\mu(N d)=\mu(N) \mu(d)$ if $(N, d)=1$, and $\mu(N d)=0$ if $(N, d)>1$, so the last equation gives us
\begin{aligned}
s_k(n) & =\mu(N) h(N) \sum_{\substack{d \mid a \\
(N, d)=1}} f\left(\frac{a}{d}\right) \mu(d) h(d)=f(a) \mu(N) h(N) \sum_{\substack{d \mid a \\
(N, d)=1}} \mu(d) \frac{h(d)}{f(d)} \\
& =f(a) \mu(N) h(N) \prod_{\substack{p \mid a \\
p \nmid N}}\left(1-\frac{h(p)}{f(p)}\right)=f(a) \mu(N) h(N) \frac{\prod_{p \mid a N}\left(1-\frac{h(p)}{f(p)}\right)}{\prod_{p \mid N}\left(1-\frac{h(p)}{f(p)}\right)} \\
& =f(a) \mu(N) h(N) \frac{F(k)}{f(k)} \frac{f(N)}{F(N)}=\frac{F(k) \mu(N) h(N)}{F(N)}=\frac{F(k) g(N)}{F(N)} .
\end{aligned}
My question:
How can I deduce that
$$ \sum_{\substack{d \mid a \\
(N, d)=1}} \mu(d) \frac{h(d)}{f(d)} = 
\prod_{\substack{p \mid a \\
p \nmid N}}\left(1-\frac{h(p)}{f(p)}\right)$$
by

Theorem 2.18 If $f$ is multiplicative we have
$$ \sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) f(d)=\prod_{p \mid n}(1-f(p)) . $$
Proof. Let
$$ g(n)=\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) f(d) $$
Then $g$ is multiplicative, so to determine $g(n)$ it suffices to
compute $g\left(p^a\right)$. But
$$ g\left(p^a\right)=\sum_{d \mid p^a} \mu(d) f(d)=\mu(1) f(1)+\mu(p)
> f(p)=1-f(p) $$
Hence
$$ g(n)=\prod_{p \mid n} g\left(p^a\right)=\prod_{p \mid n}(1-f(p)) $$


Let $F(d)=h(d)/f(d)$ if $(N,d)=1$ and $0$ otherwise. This is a multiplicative function (assuming $f$ and $h$ are).
You now apply Theorem 2.18 to $\sum_{d\mid a}\mu(d)F(d)$ (noting that the factor $(1-F(p))$ is just $1$ if $p\mid N$).

But LHS has a restriction of (N,d)=1

Right, but that's why I set $F(d)$ to be $0$ if $(N,d)\neq 1$. Then $\sum_{d\mid a}\mu(d)F(d)$ is the same as that with the restriction of $(N,d)=1$ added.
